# How can I access the dates from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to put the dates in a variable in order to pass them via django to `charts.js`.

Now I have the problem, that I cannot access the dates, since they are apparently in the second row.

`print df['Open']` or print `df['High']` works `fpr` example, but `print df['Date']` doesn't work.

Can you guys tell me how I can restructure the `df` in a way that I can print the dates as well?

Thanks a lot for your help and kind regards.

[Dates are not accessable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esDK5.png)

Answer (score 4):

First column is called `index`, so for select need:

```
print (df.index)

dates = df.index
```

Or add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for new column from values of `index`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
dates = df['Date']
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Open':[1,2,3], 'High':[8,9,2]},
                  index=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3))
df.index.name = 'Date'
print (df)
            High  Open
Date                  
2015-01-01     8     1
2015-01-02     9     2
2015-01-03     2     3

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03'], 
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq='D')
```

---

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df['Date'])
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-03
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print (df['Date'])
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-03
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```